# Can a jQuery $.post call itself again from the callback?

Tags: ajax, jquery

The use case would be if the response it gets isn't what it wanted it can call itself again.

```
$.post(qrLoginAjax.ajaxurl, { 
    userID : '11234324'
},function( response ) {
    if (response.userID != 'undefined'){
        //do stuff
    } else {
        // call $.post again
    }
});
```

How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var sendAjax = function() {
    $.post('/foo', function(result) {
        if (response.userID != 'undefined') {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // resend the AJAX request by calling the sendAjax function again
            sendAjax();
        }
    });
};

sendAjax();
```

But sending AJAX requests like this seems like a bad design decision in my opinion. You should ensure that you don't get into an infinite recursion by using for example a number of retries counter.

Comment: In your word how could this be implemented with a good design?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a function, and call itself. For example with $.ajax, you can do this:

```
function do_stuff(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        success: function(data){
            // Stuff
        },
        error: function(){
            do_stuff();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the general principle of a recursive function, but it is highly recommended that you test conditions or set a maximum number of tries so it doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` keyword of Javascript. As we all know, that refers to the object it belongs to. For example:

```js
$.post(qrLoginAjax.ajaxurl, 
      {
        userID : '11234324'
      }, 
      function( response ) {
          if (response.userID != 'undefined') {
             //do stuff
          } 
          else {
            $.post(this);
          }
      }
);
```